# Generators and Covariance Operators of Diffusions

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

For a constant coefficient Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process, how should I think about the relationship between the infinitesimal generator of the process and the covariance operator of the process (or, equivalently, its precision operator)?  Is there a meaningful relationship?